# Can not install Google Cloud Platform Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-platform, google-plugin-eclipse

When I try to install the Google Cloud Platform Eclipse, Eclipse does install everything except said plugin:

[image: Installation]

Does anyone know how to make Eclipse install this plugin?

I tried deleting Google Cloud Tools and reinstalling it and it didn't work. Do I have to reinstall eclipse? Or can I fix it without reinstalling eclipse?

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using? [Eclipse 4.6 is the minimum version supported](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/release-notes#160_march_12_2018).

Comment: I have eclipse version 4.4.2,
Thank you I will try to update it.

Comment: Hi. Please, answer back when you have updated Eclipse, to let me know if it worked.

Comment: yes it worked thanks

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, [Eclipse 4.6 is the minimum version supported](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/release-notes#160_march_12_2018).

Updating solves the installation issue.